# How can I query 3 tables, using php/mySQL, keeping all the categories in the right table?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables.

- photos
- joins
- categories
  I would like to get a record of each photo with all of it's categories.

photos table:

[image: photos table]

joins table:

[image: joins table]

categories table:

[image]

This code gets all of the photos, but doesn't group the categories. I only want each photo to display once:

```
//define table
$tbl = "photos";
$joinsTbl = "joins";
$catsTbl = "categories";

//write query
$query = "SELECT $tbl.photoID, $tbl.photoSRC, $tbl.photoCredit, $joinsTbl.categoryID, $catsTbl.photo_category
          FROM $tbl
          LEFT JOIN $joinsTbl
            INNER JOIN $catsTbl
            ON $joinsTbl.categoryID = $catsTbl.categoryID
          ON $tbl.photoID = $joinsTbl.photoID
          LIMIT 100";
```

result (where the problem is multiple results for the same photo):

```js
    [{
 "photoID": 1,
 "photoSRC": "0112_copy.jpg",
 "categoryID": null,
 "category": null
}, {
 "photoID": 2,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2484.jpg",
 "categoryID": 2,
 "category": "Deicing"
}, {
 "photoID": 2,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2484.jpg",
 "categoryID": 3,
 "category": "Training"
}, {
 "photoID": 2,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2484.jpg",
 "categoryID": 6,
 "category": "Familiarization"
}, {
 "photoID": 2,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2484.jpg",
 "categoryID": 7,
 "category": "Vehicle"
}, {
 "photoID": 3,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2492.jpg",
 "categoryID": 3,
 "category": "Training"
}, {
 "photoID": 3,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2492.jpg",
 "categoryID": 1,
 "category": "Water"
}, {
 "photoID": 3,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2492.jpg",
 "categoryID": 2,
 "category": "Deicing"
}, {
 "photoID": 3,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2492.jpg",
 "categoryID": 3,
 "category": "Training"
}, {
 "photoID": 3,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2492.jpg",
 "categoryID": 4,
 "category": "Instruction"
}, {
 "photoID": 3,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2492.jpg",
 "categoryID": 5,
 "category": "Spray"
},
```

**Using GROUP BY**

```
    $query = "SELECT $tbl.photoID, $tbl.photoSRC, $tbl.photoCredit, $joinsTbl.categoryID, $catsTbl.photo_category
          FROM $tbl
          LEFT JOIN $joinsTbl
            INNER JOIN $catsTbl
            ON $joinsTbl.categoryID = $catsTbl.categoryID
          ON $tbl.photoID = $joinsTbl.photoID
          GROUP BY $tbl.photoID
          LIMIT 100";
```

Result (where the problem is only 1 of the categories appears):

```js
[{
 "photoID": 1,
 "photoSRC": "0112_copy.jpg",
 "categoryID": null,
 "category": null
}, {
 "photoID": 2,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2484.jpg",
 "categoryID": 2,
 "category": "Deicing"
}, {
 "photoID": 3,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2492.jpg",
 "categoryID": 3,
 "category": "Training"
}, {
 "photoID": 4,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_20431.jpg",
 "categoryID": 44,
 "category": "Type I"
}, {
 "photoID": 5,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_3562.jpg",
 "categoryID": null,
 "category": null
}, {
 "photoID": 6,
 "photoSRC": "001pasp5.jpg",
 "categoryID": 2,
 "category": "Deicing"
}]
```

What I am trying to get (with multiple categories):

```js
{
 "photoID": 2,
 "photoSRC": "IMG_2484.jpg",
 "photoCredit": "Michael Chaput",
 "categoryID": 2,
 "category": {"Deicing", "Training", "Scary", "Fluids"}
},
```

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  All those non-aggregated columns must be included in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also, what's the point of `GROUP BY` without aggregation???

Comment: out of curiosity, are you using dadabik? because the solution of using group_concat (which is probably the best solution) may result in a strange appearance unless you use the right separator.

Comment: @eric could you give me an example of which columns and aggregation. Not quite following you.

Comment: @electricjelly no I have never heard of dadabik.

Comment: @Bruce.Norton These columns are not aggregated, so need to be in `GROUP BY`: `$tbl.photoID, $tbl.photoSRC, $tbl.photoCredit, $joinsTbl.categoryID, $catsTbl.photo_category`

Comment: @Bruce.Norton MySQL is probably the only dbms that let your query run.  Other dbms will not even run your query.  It will error out.  The query below use proper aggregation.  All non-aggregated columns are in GROUP BY.  The only column not in `GROUP BY` is the one aggregated by `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate:

```
$query = "SELECT $tbl.photoID, $tbl.photoSRC, $tbl.photoCredit, $joinsTbl.categoryID,  
                 GROUP_CONCAT($catsTbl.photo_category SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
          FROM $tbl
          LEFT JOIN $joinsTbl
          INNER JOIN $catsTbl
             ON $joinsTbl.categoryID = $catsTbl.categoryID
             ON $tbl.photoID = $joinsTbl.photoID
          GROUP BY $tbl.photoID, $tbl.photoSRC, $tbl.photoCredit, $joinsTbl.categoryID
          LIMIT 100"
```

Comment: It's giving an error, but no info, despite having display errors on
https://gist.github.com/brucenorton/63881fac229c76e757225472d62bfda7

Comment: And what are the errors? Report the MySQL exception. Also I edit above for proper aggregate queries. MySQL is infamous for not requiring full `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Wait...what is repeating? In fact, what is wrong with output? The pretty print version shows 100 distinct photos for each brace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Parfait, here is what worked for me:

```
$query = "SELECT $tbl.photoID, $tbl.photoSRC, $tbl.photoCredit, $joinsTbl.categoryID,  
      GROUP_CONCAT($catsTbl.photo_category SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
      FROM $tbl
      LEFT JOIN $joinsTbl
      INNER JOIN $catsTbl
         ON $joinsTbl.categoryID = $catsTbl.categoryID
         ON $tbl.photoID = $joinsTbl.photoID
      GROUP BY $tbl.photoID
      LIMIT 100";
```

Only difference, is that I only group by one column.
Here is the full gist:
https://gist.github.com/brucenorton/63881fac229c76e757225472d62bfda7

Comment: Reconsider running aggregate SQL queries like this (which was my first version of answer -see history). `GROUP BY` should contain ALL non-aggregated columns. MySQL unfortunately allows this invalid SQL with its [ONLY FULL GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) feature set to off -a disservice to new SQL coders. This is no longer the default in later MySQL versions. All other RDBMS's will fail with this query!

Comment: With multiple "group by"s I get duplicated photos:
http://aws.sureconsult.ca/app/select_photos_parfait.php
With above, I get one photo with multiple categories.
http://aws.sureconsult.ca/app/select_photos_categories2.php
I am maybe not understanding something?

Comment: Using a partial `GROUP BY` as you show here, only that field is grouped on and takes the first value of every other non-aggregated column. The reason of the repetition is because the *CategoryID* aligns with *Category* values. So *photos* repeat for each different *CategoryID*. To fix, add `GROUP_CONCAT(CategoryID)` or `MIN(CategoryID)` aggregates and remove *CategoryID* from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` in my above answer.